# VLC with telnet interface does not show GUI, consumes CPU

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, telnet

I want to control the VLC player via telnet. What I want is to be able to set media, play it and pause it.

I found this command:

```
vlc.exe -I telnet --telnet-password test
```

It does work, I can connect but I see no GUI at all:

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax)
                                                   Password:
Welcome, Master
```

The telnet CLI does not echo the commands, which is a bit annoying. Now I tried to add media:

```
add "D:\somepath\movie.mp4"
```

After that, the vlc.exe process starts eating 2 CPU cores.

When I type `playlist` I see:

```
> > +----[ Playlist - Undefined ]
| 2 - Playlist
|   5 - movie.mp4" [played 3935 times]
| 3 - Media Library
+----[ End of playlist ]
```

The play count is a bit suspicious, right? When I type `stop`, CPU usage drops to one full core.

So, what's wrong?

Comment: Dude I have exactly the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Comment: On my computer, telnet+GUI works the following way: Only use the `--telnet-password` command line switch but not the `-I telnet` switch. Then go to the menu: View->Add Interface->Telnet (unfortunately, this must be done with the mouse). After doing this, the GUI is still running and I can access vlc using telnet.